# Outlook add-in Accessing last reply in a conversation

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Is it possible somehow to get the latest reply in a conversation? That is, when you open a mail I need the body of the latest reply in that mail.

Do I have to parse or is there a way to access the top mail using the API?

Comment: Any luck on this one? I'm trying to figure this out right now!